# PHP Password different all time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using following method for saving password in database during signup.

```
'reg_password'=>password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 15]),
```

I am using following method for during login.

```
'Password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 15])
```

Everytime I am getting different hashed password How can I resolve this? and sorry for my weak English.

Comment: login requires `password_verify()` and not `password_hash()`.

Comment: During login you should use `password_verify()`.

Comment: Use `password_verify()` when logging in

Comment: ^ I said that lol

Comment: ^^^ So did I ;)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php for login

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes you did :-) but the more the merrier, that way it "should" sink in.

Comment: Just adding context to the "use `password_verify()`" fest - we know the hashes are always different; that's how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`password_hash()` helps to convert the user's input password for the first time at sign_up and will then return this information (hash + salt) in a single string suitable for storing with the user's record in the database. It can not be used to check whether the user input matches with the already hashed password in the database. For that you need to use the `password_verify()` method to check if the password exists.For Example

```
'Password' => password_verify($this->input->post('password'), $stored_password);
```